# When using knife configure what is admin.pem used for?

Tags: chef-infra

Can someone explain what admin.pem and the associated admin-client-key and admin-client-name options in knife configure are for?

My understanding is that the validation.pem is used to sign the HTTP headers when communicating with chef-server so that new clients can have their key-pair generated and private key downloaded for subsequent communications. That makes sense for chef-clients who are bootstrapped and on first run need to register and get their own keys. But why with knife do you need both validation and admin.pem ?

What does admin.pem do that validation.pem can't and what private key is downloaded to the knife.rb.. is it a new admin users private key or just a new client private key.

confused.

thanks
flo

Comment: For a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462252/chef-chef-validator-pem-security/19468000#19468000

Answer (score 1):

Admin pems can create validators. Validators are unable to create other validators.

Comment: mmm ok. Are you saying that the admin.pem is needed to elevate the knife configure privileges to that of admin user so the client key generated and returned to the workstation is able to self generate it's own validation.pem keys that will be transferred to clients during bootstrapping which will in-turn use that key to communicate with the chef-server and request it's own client key on first chef-client run ?

Comment: http://docs.opscode.com/manage_server_hosted_permissions.html and http://docs.opscode.com/auth_authorization.html